# Convert to preg from ereg

Tags: php, deprecated, ereg

I don't know how to convert from `ereg` to `preg`; could someone help me with this line?

```
if (ereg("[/[/]",$keyword)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
if (preg_match('/[/[/]/', $keyword)) { ... }
```

Comment: Then I get this message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in /home3/username/public_html/components/com_eventlist/views/details/view.html.php on line 166

Comment: @TomScottUnnebergNielsen Please remove the "..." part, sorry, this was for meant for your code inside the braces.

Comment: Then I got this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /home3/tom3008/public_html/components/com_eventlist/views/details/view.html.php on line 174

Comment: @TomScottUnnebergNielsen To solve this I would need to see your whole code. Are alle braces closed correctly? `if (...) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: No, he's not closing all braces. He just copy and pasted, not knowing what your answer was explaining (which is why "[try this](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help10)" is bad for answers). Your regex delimiters also conflict with the actual match pattern.

Comment: I just sent you on Facebook. Thanks!!:)

Comment: Did you get it @TIIUNDER ?

Comment: @TomScottUnnebergNielsen No, sorry, please post your code here http://pastebin.com/ and share the link

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/HtVr657d @TIIUNDER

Comment: @TomScottUnnebergNielsen Take a look, I changed the line 166 like in my answer at http://pastebin.com/VBJgb5kS